# Pass an array of data to PHP script, and insert it to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, post, parameters

I have an client app written on c#, from which i need to insert information, using api interface. I trying to make that api, but i'm really newbie in web development. From what i understand, i need to make a POST (for better security) `x-www-form-urlencoded` request to my web api script. I have a post parameters like this:

`client_id=1234&client_version=4&data_key[0]=encryptionkey1&data_selenium_browser[0]=firefox46&data_driver_path[0]=c:\user\appdata\client\drivers\s_driver1.exe&data_key[1]=encryptionkey2&data_selenium_browser[1]&data_driver_path[1]=c:\user\appdata\client\drivers\s_driver2.exe`

There can be any amount of  `data_key` and `data_selenium_browser` and `data_driver_path`.

So i parse all that parameters, and now i need to insert an array of `data_key` and `data_selenium_browser` and `data_driver_path` for each user id.

I have question, what would be better way to pass array of parameters and how can i store it inside mysql? Currently from what i have thought, i can do a separate table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE clients_data (
   client_id int ,
   data_key varchar(32),
   data_selenium_browser varchar(32),
   data_driver_path TEXT
);
```

So the client_id is not unique, i assume i must insert a multiple records for each user, with those parameters, and do `LEFT JOIN` or something like that, to select all that columns, when displaying user info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `foreach` loop. Here's how to do it using a PDO prepared statement.

```
$update_stmt = $conn->prepare("
    INSERT INTO clients_data (client_id, data_key, data_selenium_browser, data_driver_path)
    VALUES (:id, :key, :browser, :path)");
$update_stmt->bindParam(":id", $id);
$update_stmt->bindParam(":key", $key);
$update_stmt->bindParam(":browser", $browser);
$update_stmt->bindParam(":path", $path);
$id = $_GET['client_id'];
foreach ($_GET['data_key'] AS $index => $key) {
    $browser = $_GET['data_selenium_browser'][$index];
    $path = $_GET['data_driver_path'][$index];
    $update_stmt->execute();
}
```